# Using comment box in an Android/PhoneGap app

Tags: android, cordova, facebook-comments

My problem is with the Facebook SDK, Android, PhoneGap and the Comments Box.

I'm not familiar enough with the Facebook SDK that I would really know what the difference is between the two ways of using the Comments Box, but there seems to be two separate ways to include commenting on a "page". At least they seem to produce different kinds of errors.

Symptom one is that with the "old" way of doing it there's a problem with the comments box iframe refusing the request since the "protocols, hosts and ports must match" or similar. The page is from "file://..." and the iframe obviously from Facebook (http and facebook.com).

With the old way is to do it like this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Symptom two is that with the "new" way of doing it your API just refuses the call. The API just tells us that the Application is not configured correctly, or similar. And obviously we cannot configure it "correctly". With a mobile website you would require the url of the service (which is coming locally from the mobile at "file://...") to match with whatever is configured, which on the other hand cannot be set to other than "http" or "https". And with an Android app it's not possible either, since Facebook would want to start our app's activity, which would then redirect the user back to start. Or something.

With the new way is to do it like this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472/

Has anyone been able to work around this or would it need a "PhoneGap" -type for apps in Facebook with reduced limitations on the requests?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/groups/androidsdkfeedback/

Comment: #Simon Cross: are you suggesting we take the Beta SDK into use?

Comment: maybe try the facebook connect phonegap plugin? https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049109/adding-facebook-comment-box-plugin-for-web-based-phonegap-app/31248141#31248141