# Adding facebook comment box plugin for web based phonegap app

Tags: facebook, cordova, comments

I am trying to add the facebook comment box to my web based app but it does not show up when I install on my phone. Is there some special plugin or methodology for getting the facebook comment plugin to work with phonegap and/or ionic? I currently have this plugin in my config:

**`<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" version="0.9.0">`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is to call the comments box from inside an iframe. The only problems with this methodology so far is logging in and setting the iframe height. I am still working on a solution

Comment: Can you please help with the code how can I call facebook comments box on ionic cordova app from Iframe? Your help would be much thanked!

Comment: Maybe he is doing it like this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252259/facebook-comment-api-phonegap#answer-21671465

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it with iframe also.
I solved resizing with https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

for login i had to change the native code.

iOS: MainViewController.m

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   

NSURL *url = [request URL];
if (![url isFileURL] && (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked))
{   //this is for loading links in external browser
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }
} else if ([[url absoluteString] containsString:@"m.facebook.com"] && [[url absoluteString] containsString:@"login"]) {

    NSString *forceInAppBrowserJS = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                     @"var loginWindow = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('%@', '_blank', 'location=yes');\n\
                                       loginWindow.addEventListener('exit', function(){\n\
                                       window.fbIframe.src = window.fbIframe.src;\n\
                                            });", url]; //reload the iframe after login, you have to assign the iframe in js 

    [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: forceInAppBrowserJS];

    return NO;

}

return [super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
}
```

Android: CordovaWebViewClient.java

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    if (!url.contains("file://")) {

        if (url.contains("m.facebook.com") && url.contains("login")) {

            String forceInAppBrowserJS = String.format("var loginWindow = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('%s', '_blank', 'location=yes,hardwareback=yes'); loginWindow.addEventListener('exit', function(){window.fbIframe.src = window.fbIframe.src;});", url);
            view.evaluateJavascript(forceInAppBrowserJS, null);

            return true;

        }

        if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
            url = "http://" + url;
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(browserIntent); //open link in external browser

        return true;

    } 

    return helper.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}
```

Comment: And, of course, you have to install the InAppBrowser plugin for Cordova